# Closing a Jar file with a Jar file

Tags: java, jar

When writting an updater for a program, I quickly realized that the program will have to be closed for the updater to work properly. I remember long ago as a new programmer seeing a strange peice of code that could edit variable values or call methods of a class in a second jar file. I was wondering if anyone knew of such code. If not I can figure out something else.

Comment: Using another JAR means that it's somewhere on your classpath, and that some Java program with main can instantiate it.  I'm not entirely sure what you're asking though - is it how to use a JAR within another class, or something else?

Comment: Uh... `System.exit(1)` will terminate the currently running Java Virtual Machine, if that's what you are asking for...

Comment: @AlexLockwood That is what I am trying to use. Think of it like this. Jar file A needs to be closed via Jar file B. Jar file B calls System.exit() in A from B. A would close, B would keep running.

Comment: @Makoto I think that might be it. EDIT: Thats it. Found the old code. Thank you.

Comment: @Taxes45 -- write an answer to your question with that code so if someone else has the same problem they'll see how you fixed it.

Comment: Jar withing a Jar .. Jarception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is the code I found](http://abondar-howto.blogspot.com/2010/06/howto-unload-jar-files-loaded-by.html). It accomplishs the same goal just with a different purpose.